# WordPress Contact 7 - Append a form with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using contact 7 plugin to generate forms for my pages. Now in one of the page, a functionality needs where the user clicks on a button/link and a form will be generated. Please consider the following image for better understanding.

[image]

And then both forms should be submitted via the same "Submit" button. Possible?
I know If it was just simple appending, I could use jQuery's .clone() or something but not sure would that work?

Comment: Is the maximum 2 forms?

Comment: @rnevius Nope, We must append as many forms as we want. If it were two forms, I would have simply added the second one and would have made it hidden. You were about to suggest the same? Right? :-)